# UserControls and viewmodels in View-First-MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm forced to use View First MVVM in a WPF application and I'm struggling to see how it can be made to work elegantly.

The root of the problem lies with nested `UserControls`. In an MVVM architecture each `UserControl` needs to have its view model assigned to its `DataContext`, this keeps the binding expressions simple, and what's more this is also the way WPF will instantiate any view generated via a `DataTemplate`.

But if a child `UserControl` has dependency properties which the parent needs to bind to its own viewmodel then the fact that the child `UserControl` has its `DataContext` set to its own viewmodel means that an 'implicit path' binding in the parent XAML file will resolve to the child's viewmodel instead of the parent's.

To work around this every parent of every `UserControl` in the application will either need to use explicit named bindings for everything by default (which is verbose, ugly and errorprone), or it will have to know whether a specific control has its `DataContext` set to its own viewmodel or not and use the appropriate binding syntax, (which is equally errorprone, and a major violation of basic encapsulation).

After days of research I haven't come across a single half decent solution to this issue. The closest thing to a solution I've come across is setting the `UserControl's` viewmodel to an inner element of the `UserControl` (the topmost `Grid` or whatever), which still leaves you facing a problem trying to bind properties of the `UserControl` itself to its own viewmodel! (`ElementName` binding won't work in this case because the binding would be declared before the named element with the viewmodel assigned to its `DataContext`).

I suspect that the reason not many other people run into this it that they are either using viewmodel first MVVM which doesn't have this issue, or they are using view first MVVM in conjunction with a dependency injection implementation that amelliorates this issue.

Does anyone have a clean solution for this please?

UPDATE:

Sample code as requested.

```xml
<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<Window x:Class="UiInteraction.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UiInteraction"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        x:Name="_this">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControl6 Text="{Binding MainWindowVmString1}"/>  
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

```cs
namespace UiInteraction
{
    // MainWindow viewmodel.
    class MainWindowVm
    {
        public string MainWindowVmString1
        {
            get { return "MainWindowVm.String1"; }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- UserControl6.xaml -->
<UserControl x:Class="UiInteraction.UserControl6" x:Name="_this"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UiInteraction">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:UserControl6Vm/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Is bound to this UserControl's own viewmodel. -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserControlVmString1}"/>

        <!-- Has its value set by the UserControl's parent via dependency property. -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=_this}"/>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

```cs
namespace UiInteraction
{
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;

    // UserControl code behind declares DependencyProperty for parent to bind to.
    public partial class UserControl6 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl6));

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace UiInteraction
{
    // UserControl's viewmodel.
    class UserControl6Vm
    {
        public string UserControlVmString1
        {
            get { return "UserControl6Vm.String1"; }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'MainWindowVmString1' property not found on 'object' ''UserControl6Vm'
>   (HashCode=44204140)'. BindingExpression:Path=MainWindowVmString1;
>   DataItem='UserControl6Vm' (HashCode=44204140); target element is
>   'UserControl6' (Name='_this'); target property is 'Text' (type
>   'String')

because in `MainWindow.xaml` the declaration `<local:UserControl6 Text="{Binding MainWindowVmString1}"/>` is attempting to resolve `MainWindowVmString1` on `UserControl6Vm`.

In `UserControl6.xaml` commenting out the declaration of the `DataContext` and the first `TextBlock` the code will work, but the `UserControl` needs a `DataContext`. In `MainWIndow1` using an `ElementName` instead of an implict path binding will also work, but in order to use the `ElementName` binding syntax you would either have to know that the `UserControl` assigns its viewmodel to its `DataContext` (encapsulation failure) or altenatively adopt a policy of using `ElementName` bindings *everywhere*. Neither of which is appealing.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? Have you looked at the WPF Application Framework provided by Microsoft? Nesting ViewModels is a common problem.

Comment: I know this question is a bit old and just bumped by Community, but the mentioned approach of *"`UserControl`'s viewmodel to an inner element"* should be the solution. I would be interested to see examples where a binding of the UserControl properties to the viewmodel is necessary - typical UserControl settings are purely UI related things or should be set on usage rather than declaration.

Comment: Any UserControl that accesses non-trivial data or configuration will commonly need to have its controls bound to its viewmodel. E.g. a settings widget, or data display widget. Only the most trival UI components have no connection to any underlying data model at all, e.g. a button where the button text is set via dependency property binding in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

An immediate solution is to use a `RelativeSource` and set it to look for the `DataContext` of a parent `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ParentViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:ChildControl MyProperty="{Binding DataContext.PropertyInParentDataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You could also treat the child viewmodels as properties of the parent viewmodel, and propagate it from the parent. That way, the parent viewmodel is aware of the children so it can update their properties. The child viewmodels also may have a `"Parent"` property which holds a reference to the parent, injected by the parent itelf upon their creation, which may grant direct access to the parent.

```
public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged values

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private ChildViewModel childViewModel;
    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel
    {
        get { return this.childViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (this.childViewModel != value)
            {
                this.childViewModel = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ChildViewModel");
            }
        }
    }       
}

<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ParentViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <local:ChildControl DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}"
            MyProperty1="{Binding PropertyInTheChildControlledByParent}"                
            MyProperty2="{Binding Parent.PropertyWithDirectAccess}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT**
Another approach and more complex would be making the parent's `DataContext` available to the child `UserControl` using an attached property. I have not fully implemented it, but it would consist in an attached property to request the feature (something like `"HasAccessToParentDT"`), in which `DependencyPropertyChanged` event you would hook up the Load and `Unload` events of the `ChildUserControl`, access the `Parent` property (available if the control is loaded) and bind its `DataContext` to a second attached property, `"ParentDataContext"`, which could then be used in xaml.

```
        <local:ChildControl BindingHelper.AccessParentDataContext="True"
            MyProperty="{Binding BindingHelper.ParentDataContext.TargetProperty}"   />
```

Comment: The first approach is an example of exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want my bindings to look like MyProperty="{Binding PropertyInParentDataContext}" instead of MyProperty="{Binding DataContext.PropertyInParentDataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}". This isn't just a stylistic consideration because errors in XAML are a nightmare to track down.

Comment: The problem with the second approach is that if the parent wants to bind to any of the ChildControl's dependency properties in addition to its DataContext then that also requires a convoluted binding expression because if one of the assigned bindings is the ChildControl's DataContext then that affects the implicit binding source for all the other binding expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution really is using the RelativeSource. The binding itself doesn't look very pretty, but it's actually very common to see. I wouldn't avoid it - this is exactly the scenario why it's there.

Another approach which you can use is a reference to a parent viewmodel, if it's logical to have it. Like I have a FlightPlan view, which shows a list of navigation point and its graphical "map" side by side. The list of points is a separate view with separate viewmodel:

```
public class PlanPointsPartViewModel : BindableBase
{

    //[...]

    private FlightPlanViewModel _parentFlightPlan;
    public FlightPlanViewModel ParentFlightPlan
    {
        get { return _parentFlightPlan; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _parentFlightPlan, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ParentFlightPlan);
        }
    } 

    //[...]

}
```

Then the view can bind to this property like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentFlightPlan.Waypoints}"
          AllowDrop="True"
          DragEnter="ListViewDragEnter"
          Drop="ListViewDrop"
          >
    [...]
</ListView>
```

However composing viewmodels like this is often quite questionable.

Comment: I don't like the idea of referencing a parent's viewmodel. While I agree in some specific situations this may be logical I wouldn't consider it a generic solution, especially when using view first MVVM where it is the view's dependency properties that primarily form the interface between the various view elements rather than a direct reference between their view models.

Comment: I agree that using RelativeSource in the manner proposed in Arthur Nune's answer is a better approach. On the one hand it doesn't quite answer the question because it can't be considered syntactically elegant, but on the other hand it is a localised generic solution. But how is using RelativeSource better than x:Naming the parent UI element and using an ElementName binding though? E.g. Text="{Binding DataContext.Text, ElementName=_this}"

Comment: Referencing parent viewmodel is surely not generic solution - I it here only as an example of a different approach (although you can also use a dependency injection in some cases, but it still doesn't solve the problem).

Comment: The RelativeSource can be better because it doesn't tightly couple one element to other which IMHO is better, however YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

What about having a ParentDataContextProperty on the second level UserControl's ViewModel. Then create a dependencyproperty on that usercontrol with the same name and let it set the value to the VM's property in the xaml.cs file. Then the Parentcontrol can bind its DataContext to the child controls dependencyproperty to provide the child VM with access to its (the parent) datacontext. The childcontrol can bind to the parent's datacontext through its own ParentDataContextProperty VM property. (should probably be named just PContext or something short).

You could create a base class deriving from UserControl that has this DependencyProperty setup so you dont need to write it for every new control.